# Regex <Div> tags but ignore the inner <div> tags

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

```
Regex = <h1 class=\"row display-row\">\\s*(.+?)s*</h1>
```

How do I capture the following into a Dictionary as key & value.

```
<div class="row display-row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 display-label">
        Text Key
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        Text Value   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use "regex" to parse html or xml.

Comment: Yet another how to parse HTML with Regex question...

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: don't use regex to parse HTML, HTML is not xml you can do alot of things that will normally be illegal, this is a situation you should be using jQuery.  If must parse html then use a HTML Parser HTMLAgility Pack or something

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Why am I only seeing this for the first time. Amazing.